# Apache Nutch 1.17 indexer rabbit not working

Tags: nutch

I am trying to push crawled documents to the rabbit. Have followed all the docs available.

1. [IndexWriters Mapping](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/NUTCH/IndexWriters#IndexWriters-Mappingsection)
2. [RabbitMQ README](https://github.com/apache/nutch/tree/master/src/plugin/indexer-rabbit)

However, I can't manage to run indexer-rabbit. Looking at the logs, there's no even mentioning above indexer-rabbit. I am just trying to make it work before further configuration. I tried connecting to RabbitMQ with a small custom program. Everythings working.

I have included indexer in nutch-site.xml as well.

```
<property>
  <name>plugin.includes</name>
  <value>protocol-http|urlfilter-(regex|validator)|parse-(html|tika)|index-(basic|anchor)|indexer-rabbit|scoring-opic|urlnormalizer-(pass|regex|basic)</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>rabbitmq.publisher.server.uri</name>
  <value>amqp://guest:guest@172.17.0.2:5672/</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>publisher.queue.type</name>
  <value>RabbitMQ</value>
</property>
```

Also, the mappings are default and seem quite right for testing.

```
<writer id="indexer_solr_1" class="org.apache.nutch.indexwriter.solr.SolrIndexWriter">
  <parameters>
    <param name="type" value="http"/>
    <param name="url" value="http://localhost:8983/solr/nutch"/>
    <param name="collection" value=""/>
    <param name="weight.field" value=""/>
    <param name="commitSize" value="1000"/>
    <param name="auth" value="false"/>
    <param name="username" value="username"/>
    <param name="password" value="password"/>
  </parameters>
  <mapping>
    <copy>
      <!-- <field source="content" dest="search"/> -->
      <!-- <field source="title" dest="title,search"/> -->
    </copy>
    <rename>
      <field source="metatag.description" dest="description"/>
      <field source="metatag.keywords" dest="keywords"/>
    </rename>
    <remove>
      <field source="segment"/>
    </remove>
  </mapping>
</writer>
<writer id="indexer_rabbit_1" class="org.apache.nutch.indexwriter.rabbit.RabbitIndexWriter">
  <parameters>
    <param name="server.uri" value="amqp://guest:guest@172.17.0.2:5672/"/>
    <param name="binding" value="false"/>
    <param name="binding.arguments" value=""/>
    <param name="exchange.name" value=""/>
    <param name="exchange.options" value="type=direct,durable=true"/>
    <param name="queue.name" value="nutch.queue"/>
    <param name="queue.options" value="durable=true,exclusive=false,auto-delete=false"/>
    <param name="routingkey" value=""/>
    <param name="commit.mode" value="multiple"/>
    <param name="commit.size" value="250"/>
    <param name="headers.static" value=""/>
    <param name="headers.dynamic" value=""/>
  </parameters>
  <mapping>
    <copy>
      <field source="title" dest="title,search"/>
    </copy>
    <rename>
      <field source="metatag.description" dest="description"/>
      <field source="metatag.keywords" dest="keywords"/>
    </rename>
    <remove>
      <field source="content"/>
      <field source="segment"/>
      <field source="boost"/>
    </remove>
  </mapping>
</writer>
```

Does anybody have any idea what am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Turned out it was my stupid mistake. Was just a slight problem. I didn't added index parameter in crawl command. Previous command looked like this.

```
./bin/crawl -s ./urls --hostdbupdate --hostdbgenerate --size-fetchlist 20 ./crawl 3
```

In this command, there no index parameter. So indexing was getting skipped. New command should be:

```
./bin/crawl -i -s ./urls --hostdbupdate --hostdbgenerate --size-fetchlist 20 ./crawl 3
```